# Unsure on how to proceed with my current programme

Tags: string, swing, netbeans

I am trying to build my first app that asks a user for any month and will result in certain events being produced through a JTextArea.

This is the first time I have used Swing within netbeans and I am new to the world of coding. I would add that I am slightly out of my depth at the moment as I don't feel I should be trying to do what I am but want to do this for a family member to replicate for fun!

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package astronomy;

/**
 *
 * @author Jamie
 */
public class AstronomyEvents extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form AstronomyEvents
 */
public AstronomyEvents() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    userInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    enterButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    clearButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    resultField = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Astronomy Events");

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter A Month"));

    jLabel1.setText("Month");

    userInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            userInputActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    enterButton.setText("Look it up!");
    enterButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            enterButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    clearButton.setText("Clear");
    clearButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            clearButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    exitButton.setText("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    resultField.setColumns(20);
    resultField.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(resultField);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(enterButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 190, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(clearButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(40, 40, 40)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 418, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(28, 28, 28))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(userInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(userInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(enterButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(clearButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(101, 101, 101))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(47, 47, 47)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(83, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(834, 517));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void userInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

}                                         

private void clearButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    userInput.setText("");
    resultField.setText("");



}                                           

private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void enterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


               if (userInput.equals ("January"))
               {
                   resultField.setText("January 1st - Mercury at Greatest Western Elongation" + "\n" + "January 2nd - Full Moon, Supermoon" + "\n" + "January 3rd & 4th - Quadrantids Meteor Shower" + "\n" + "January 17th - New Moon" + "\n" + "January 31st - Full Moon, Supermoon, Blue Moon" + "\n" + "January 31st - Total Lunar Eclipse");
               } else {
                   resultField.setText("None");

               }






}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

/* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */

```
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AstronomyEvents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AstronomyEvents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AstronomyEvents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AstronomyEvents.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AstronomyEvents().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton clearButton;
private javax.swing.JButton enterButton;
private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea resultField;
private javax.swing.JTextField userInput;
// End of variables declaration                   

private void euqals(String january) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

The code above is an extract from the Swing application I am building within netbeans and as you can see what I am trying to do is say if the user inputs "January" within the input section and upon pressing enter, display the results above.

I appreciate there will be ways for making this code better and much easier, but for now I am just looking to make it work and will look into making it easier to read later.

At the moment the result is, regardless of what  I enter, the results show, which they shouldn't.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the semicolon `;` at the end of the `if` line?

Comment: Sorry, that wasnt meant to be there I was experimenting with having the semi colon or using {} either way it doesnt like it